# How to output files in multiple paths into their respective parent folder via Gulp?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, web-frontend

I have a complicated folder structure for my project, and there are a bunch of folders, but under all of them there's something identical, which is a folder called 'es6' that stores all the es6 javascript files. Basically what I want to do is:

1) to transpile all these files to es5 whenever there's an edit detected

2) to output each of these files into their RESPECTIVE parent folder

My code looks like this but it leads me nowhere:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var path = require('path')
var babel = require('gulp-babel')

gulp.task('es6', function() {
    gulp.src('./src/**/es6/*.es6.js', { base: '.' })
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['env']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/*.js'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/es6/*.es6.js')
})

gulp.task('default', ['es6', 'watch'])
```

Thanks.